# Why Google Cloud Run gettings massive container restart / new instance creation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, google-cloud-run, mongodb-atlas

I've been using Google Cloud Run for a year now and the issue with cloud run containers restarts / new container start is from the beginning.

I've hosted Node + MongoDB app in Cloud Run, but cloud run container is restarting frequently. It's getting around 10 - 12 requests / second, couldn't find any performance bottleneck, requests are serving smoothly, sometimes requests are served more than normal time, might be new container instance cold start delay.

[image: Google Cloud Run Container Restart]

The issue I am facing is the HIGH Number of connections to the MONGODB Server. After some research I could find that I've to close mongodb connection on node process exit so I've added a graceful shutdown function.

```
// Function to terminate the app gracefully:
const gracefulShutdown = async () => {
    console.log(`MONGODB CONNECTION CLOSED!`);
    await mongoose.connection.close();
};

// This will handle process.exit():
process.on('exit', gracefulShutdown);

// This will handle kill commands, such as CTRL+C:
process.on('SIGINT', gracefulShutdown);
process.on('SIGTERM', gracefulShutdown);

// This will prevent dirty exit on code-fault crashes:
process.on('uncaughtException', gracefulShutdown);
```

But even after adding this, I couldn't find this graceful shutdown function is invoked while checking logs.

1. Does google cloud run really signals when the nodejs process in the container crashed?
2. Is there any way to identity a container restart or new instance creation in cloud run?

Here is the MongoDB connection code

```
exports.connect = () => {
    try {
        mongoose
            .connect(MONGO.URI, {
                useCreateIndex: true,
                keepAlive: 1,
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true,
                useFindAndModify: false,
            })
            .then((docs) => {
                console.log(`DB Connected`);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(`err`, err);
            });
        return mongoose.connection;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`#### Error Connecting DB`, err);
        console.log(`Mongo URI: `, MONGO.URI);
    }
};
```

Sometimes cloud run issues a high number of connections to MONGODB, and hits the connection limit of 1500 connections.

[image: Google Cloud Run MongoDB High Connection issue]

Any suggestions are appreciated! I've been facing this issue for a year now.

Comment: do you have special parameter on Cloud Run? Especially the concurrency param? Do you have more detail on these connexion? Do you have instance crash or unexpected behavior that can lead to this creation?

Comment: I don't see anything in your question that relates to container starts, stops or restarts. What I'm guessing is happening is you are creating Mongo clients in your application incorrectly and that is responsible for your runaway connection counts.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere concurrency set to 80 that's the default. I couldn't find any instance crash or unexpected behavior while checking the stacktrace logs

Comment: @D.SM I've updated the question with connection code, I am not sure that's causing the issue

Comment: How, and when do you call your connect function?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere in the entry file where express app server is created, in index.js file directly on starting

Comment: Hmm, called only once when the server start, and then cached, right?

Comment: Not cached I think, In normal case it pools around 20 connections but when a spike in traffic comes (30req/sec) to the cloud run everything mess up and cloud run will handle traffic but high number of connections creating to mongodb, after a few minutes it will go down.

Answer (score 2):

You should not start the node process using `npm` or `yarn` but directly as `CMD ["node", "index.js"]` (when you are inside a Docker container using Dockerfile)

Explanation here https://maximorlov.com/process-signals-inside-docker-containers/